Session data lost after flask app is redirected to spotify authentication URL
I am using authorization code flow to work with Spotify API.
@app.route('/login')
def login():

    scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'

    print(session['code_verifier'])
    print(session['code_verifier'])
    print(session['code_verifier'])
    print(session['code_verifier'])

    params = {
        'client_id': app.config['CLIENT_ID'],
        'response_type': 'code',
        'scope': scope,
        'redirect_uri': app.config['REDIRECT_URI'],
        'show_dialog': True,
        'code_challenge_method': 'S256',
        'code_challenge': session['code_challenge']
    }

    auth_url = f"{AUTH_URL}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}"

    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():

    if 'error' in request.args:
        return jsonify({"error": request.args['error']})
   
    if 'code' in request.args:

        req_body  = {
            'code': request.args['code'],
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': app.config['REDIRECT_URI'],
            'client_id': app.config['CLIENT_ID'],
            'client_secret': app.config['CLIENT_SECRET'],
            'code_verifier': session['code_verifier']
        }

        response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data = req_body)

        token_info = response.json() 

        session['access_token'] = token_info['access_token']

        session['refresh_token'] = token_info['refresh_token']

        session['expires_at'] = datetime.now().timestamp()+ token_info['expires_in']

        return render_template('/main_choose.html')

it appears that the session data is lost after I am redirected to the auth_url. can anyone explain or help me solve this issue?
I tried doing this:
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'

app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True

but it didn't work. I have disabled all extensions on google chrome web browser, and have enabled third party cookies. I don't know what else to do.

Did you try using the supports_credentials=True argument?
I have this in my code, and everything works perfectly:
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r'/*': {'origins': config.FRONT_URL}})

Make sure to replace config.FRONT_URL with your actual front-end URL.
Here’s what the documentation says:
https://i.sstatic.net/cwIYrnig.png
https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
